# Why does subsection counter not reset in appendix?

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices, sections-paragraphs

So when I put subsections in the appendix, the counter does not reset after starting new chapters. I'm about to change the subsections to unnamed sections, but still wondering why the counter does not reset. Maybe it is a bug?

This is the code that will show the problem. When I change this into a pdf file, the last two subsections show up as A.0.3 and B.0.4 instead of A.0.1 and B.0.1

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{chap1}
    \section{sec1.1}
    \subsection{sub1.1.1}

    \subsection{sub1.1.2}

    \appendix

    \chapter{app1}
    \subsection{app1.0.1}
    \chapter{app2}
    \subsection{app2.0.1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Only `\section` resets `\subsection`. Use `\section`.

Comment: You put `\section` and `\subsection` in your main matter stuff, why do you think `\subsection` should reset the number in the appendix suddenly if doesn't do it before? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I put section, because I wanted a section, not just to reset the counter. In the appendix I would expect chapter to reset it. Chapter resets the section counter, so why not the subsection counter?

Comment: @PeterRaeves: That's an old 'bug' (or design feature, call it what you like). But with a new distribution and the 2015-format this is removed. Otherwise use `fixltx2e` package.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just changed them to section*, so they would not be in the toc, because what I actually wanted to achieve was just that... Thanks for explaining though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the O.P. uses an older (pre 2015-release) of the LaTeX core, the section number isn't reset. Then `fixltx2e` should be used. (I've tested with a TeXLive 2014 version still on my computer)

With the new kernel this isn't necessary any longer

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % Does no harm, even in a 2015 release. 
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{chap1}
    \section{sec1.1}
    \subsection{sub1.1.1}

    \subsection{sub1.1.2}

    \appendix

    \chapter{app1}
    \subsection{app1.0.1}
    \chapter{app2}
    \subsection{app2.0.1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian)` though.

Comment: @PeterRaeves: Strange: `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16` on my machine, it works out of the box, even without `fixltx2e`

Comment: Hmm when I check synaptic it says my texlive version is from 20141024, but when i check pdftex it says I'm using 1.40.15 from 2015... So not really sure what's going on. Anyway, the problem is solved, so no need to worry I suppose.

Comment: @PeterRaeves: Well, it's solved yes, in that sense. I forgot to mention: The binary version is one aspect, the TeX format version is another one. You've the older format (but you did want to make another effect anyway ;-))